# Select Count of one table into another

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I have one SQL statement as:

```
SELECT   ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_ID, ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_TTL_DES,
         ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_CNTNT_T, ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_PUB_DT, 
         ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_AUTH_NM, ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_URL,
         ARTICLES.MEDIA_URL, ARTICLES.ARTCL_SRC_ID, SOURCES.ARTCL_SRC_NM,
         MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_DESCRIP
FROM     RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_ARTICLE ARTICLES,
         RSKLMOBILEB2E.MEDIA_TYPE MEDIA, 
         RSKLMOBILEB2E.ARTICLE_SOURCE SOURCES
WHERE    ARTICLES.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF = MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF
AND      ARTICLES.ARTCL_SRC_ID = SOURCES.ARTCL_SRC_ID  
AND      ARTICLES.ARTCL_SRC_ID = 1
ORDER BY ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_PUB_DT;
```

Now I need to combine another SQL statement into one which is:

```
SELECT   COUNT(*)
FROM     RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_LIKES LIKES, 
         RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_ARTICLE ARTICLES
WHERE    LIKES.NEWS_ARTCL_ID = ARTICLES.NEWS_ARTCL_ID;
```

Not sure how I can achieve this as I am new to Oracle. Basically I have one table which contains articles and I need to include the user likes which is in another table.

Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT   ART.NEWS_ARTCL_ID, ART.NEWS_ARTCL_TTL_DES,
         ART.NEWS_ARTCL_CNTNT_T, ART.NEWS_ARTCL_PUB_DT,
         ART.NEWS_ARTCL_AUTH_NM, ART.NEWS_ARTCL_URL,
         ART.MEDIA_URL, ART.ARTCL_SRC_ID, SRC.ARTCL_SRC_NM,
         MED.MEDIA_TYPE_DESCRIP, LIK.TOTAL
FROM     RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_ARTICLE ART,
         RSKLMOBILEB2E.MEDIA_TYPE MED,
         RSKLMOBILEB2E.ARTICLE_SOURCE SRC,
         (SELECT   AR1.NEWS_ARTCL_ID, COUNT(*) TOTAL
          FROM     RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_ARTICLE AR1,
                   RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_LIKES LK1
          WHERE    AR1.NEWS_ARTCL_ID      = LK1.NEWS_ARTCL_ID) LIK
WHERE    ART.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF = MED.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF
AND      ART.ARTCL_SRC_ID       = SRC.ARTCL_SRC_ID
AND      ART.ARTCL_SRC_ID       = 1
AND      ART.NEWS_ARTCL_ID      = LIK.NEWS_ARTCL_ID
ORDER BY ART.NEWS_ARTCL_PUB_DT;
```

Comment: Hi @Marco,
I am trying to select top 10 'liked' articles between dates, I tried the using BETWEEN clause to select between dates but not sure how to select top 10 liked articles. Could you advise?

Comment: Try to add `and rownum <= 10` to it. I always forget if this is after the `order by` or before. If this does not work then you must do `select * from (the-select-from above) where rownum <=10;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little rusty on Oracle but I think that the above answer might fail if there are no likes on an article and those articles might fail to be brought back.

Should the join between:

ART.NEWS_ARTCL_ID      = LIK.NEWS_ARTCL_ID

be a left outer join, so that the query would read:

```
    SELECT   ART.NEWS_ARTCL_ID, ART.NEWS_ARTCL_TTL_DES,
         ART.NEWS_ARTCL_CNTNT_T, ART.NEWS_ARTCL_PUB_DT,
         ART.NEWS_ARTCL_AUTH_NM, ART.NEWS_ARTCL_URL,
         ART.MEDIA_URL, ART.ARTCL_SRC_ID, SRC.ARTCL_SRC_NM,
         MED.MEDIA_TYPE_DESCRIP, LIK.TOTAL
FROM     RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_ARTICLE ART,
         RSKLMOBILEB2E.MEDIA_TYPE MED,
         RSKLMOBILEB2E.ARTICLE_SOURCE SRC,
         (SELECT   AR1.NEWS_ARTCL_ID, COUNT(*) TOTAL
          FROM     RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_ARTICLE AR1,
                   RSKLMOBILEB2E.NEWS_LIKES LK1
          WHERE    AR1.NEWS_ARTCL_ID      = LK1.NEWS_ARTCL_ID) LIK
WHERE    ART.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF = MED.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF
AND      ART.ARTCL_SRC_ID       = SRC.ARTCL_SRC_ID
AND      ART.ARTCL_SRC_ID       = 1
AND      ART.NEWS_ARTCL_ID   (+)= LIK.NEWS_ARTCL_ID
ORDER BY ART.NEWS_ARTCL_PUB_DT;
```

Comment: Hi @steve
I have used ART.NEWS_ARTCL_ID = LIK.NEWS_ARTCL_ID only in the subquery, and if there are no Likes, this still works and returns 0 for the Likes.